# Calculating a double integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, special-functions

I want to calculate the following integral:
$$\int^{10}_{0}\int^{\pi}_{0}\sqrt{(37-\frac{45\cdot37\cdot x^2}{74\cdot 150})^2\cdot \sin(t)^2-(40-\frac{27\cdot37\cdot x^2}{16\cdot 150})^2\cdot \cos(t)^2}\,dt\,\,dx$$

It is rather a complex integral and I am not sure how to solve it all at once. I have tried first calculating the inner integral, ie:
$$\int^{\pi}_{0}\sqrt{(37-\frac{45\cdot37\cdot x^2}{74\cdot 150})^2\cdot \sin(t)^2-(40-\frac{27\cdot37\cdot x^2}{16\cdot 150})^2\cdot \cos(t)^2}\,dt$$

Here is the respective Mathematica code:

```
    Integrate[ Sqrt[(37 - 45 37x^2/(74 150))^2) Sin[t]^2
                    -(40 - 27 37x^2/(16 150))^2) Cos[t]^2], {t, 0, Pi}]
```

The answer included an elliptic integral function (`EllipticE`), where one of the parameters is expressed in terms of $x$.

Then I tried using the command `Integrate[%,{x,0,10}]` in order to compute the full integral shown above (where `%` is the answer of the inner integral, as in my notebook it is the last generated result). However, Mathematica did not compute it. Instead it displayed the input in the symbolic form.

Why did it do that? What can I do in order to compute the full integral?

Comment: You may put Mathematica code in your question. Besides, mma may not able to calculate it, I guess.

Comment: Have you tried using NIntegrate?

Comment: @MarcoB NIntegrate just returns multiple errors, It does not work

Comment: `NIntegrate[
 Sqrt[((37) - ((45*37*x^2)/(74*150))^2)*
    Sin[t]^2 - ((37) - ((27*37*x^2)/(16*150))^2)*Cos[t]^2], {t, 0, 
  Pi}, {x, 0, 10}]` produces `268.756 + 35.8662 I` and a warning about the slow convergence.

Comment: The integrand in your `Mathematica` code is different than that in the `TeX` form.  Which one are you going to integrate?

Comment: @Artes: The integrand in my comment coinsides with the one in the Mathematica code by OP.

Comment: `NIntegrate[
 Sqrt[((37) - ((45*37*x^2)/(74*150))^2)*
    Sin[t]^2 - ((37) - (40 - (27*37*x^2)/(16*150))^2)*Cos[t]^2], {t, 
  0, Pi}, {x, 0, 10}]` results in `506.271 + 44.0558 I`.

Comment: Such manner of defining a hard problem is not informative enough. Could You please restate the problem with the original formulation. This is difficult because this is involving the `EllipticE` function and the concept of integrals either complete in `Reals` or over the `Complexes`.

Comment: @user64494 In what order does Mathematica integrate? Doe it first integrate in terms of $t$ and then $x$?

Comment: An you please simplify by multiplying out???

Answer (score 10):

This is an interesting example where **new improvements** in version *Mathematica 12.2* of **elliptic functions handling** appear important to get a correct result.

```
TraditionalForm[
  intd[x_] = FullSimplify[ 
             Integrate[ Sqrt[(37 - (45 37 x^2)/(74 150))^2 Sin[t]^2 
                              - (40 - (27 37 x^2)/(16 150))^2 Cos[t]^2],
                        {t, 0, Pi}, Assumptions -> #], #] &[0 <= x <= 10]]
```

[image]

while in *version 12.1* this yields `intdX`:

```
intdX[x_]=  1/10 (740-3x^2) EllipticE[1 + (32000-333 x^2)^2/(1600 (740-3x^2)^2)]
```

Let's compare the integrands in *12.2* and in the former version

```
GraphicsRow[ 
  Plot[ ReIm @ #[x], {x, 0, 10}, PlotStyle -> Thick, Evaluated -> True, 
        PlotLabels -> Placed[{"Re", "Im"}, Above]] & /@ {intd, intdX}]
```

[image]

If the system returns the "unevaluated" formula it means that **there is no simpler expression in terms of the known (to the system) functions**. This is why we use  numerical integration:

```
NIntegrate[ intd[x], {x, 0, 10}]
```

> ```
>  433.168
> ```

while

```
NIntegrate[ intdX[x], {x, 0, 10}]
```

> ```
>  433.168 + 293.062 I
> ```

Answer (score 1):

12.2.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (December 12, 2020)

gives these results using antiderivate with integration limits 0 and Pi:

```
Plot[{Re[NIntegrate[Sqrt[(37 - 45*37*(x^2/(74*150)))^2*Sin[t]^2 - 
         (40 - 27*37*(x^2/(16*150)))^2*Cos[t]^2], {t, 0, Pi}, 
WorkingPrecision -> 50]], 
 Im[(1/400)*(32000 - 333*x^2)*
EllipticE[(1900160000 - 28416000*x^2 + 125289*x^4)/
         (32000 - 333*x^2)^2]]}, {x, 0, 8}, 
PlotStyle -> {Blue, Dashed}]

Plot[{Im[NIntegrate[Sqrt[(37 - 45*37*(x^2/(74*150)))^2*Sin[t]^2 - 
         (40 - 27*37*(x^2/(16*150)))^2*Cos[t]^2], {t, 0, Pi}]], 
 Re[(1/400)*(32000 - 333*x^2)*
EllipticE[(1900160000 - 28416000*x^2 + 125289*x^4)/
         (32000 - 333*x^2)^2]]}, {x, 0, 8}, 
PlotStyle -> {Blue, Dashed}]
```

Comment: Interestingly the Hypergeometric function appears, if the range of x is extended to 10...

Comment: `40 - (333*x^2)/800` changes sign at x about 9.8